# Android Paypal Integration

Tags: android, paypal

I am trying to integrate paypal as one of payment gateway in my app and it returns the following error once I click on the pay button.

**Error** 
 *java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService@b122d3c8 with Intent { cmp=com.nepflights.app/com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService }: java.lang.RuntimeException: Service extras required. Please see the docs.*

The code for paypal is as follows,

```
  public void onClick (View v){
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnPaypal:
                PayPalPayment YourTicket = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(1), "USD",
                        "Your Total ticket price:",
                        PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);

                Intent intent = new Intent(payActivity.this, PaymentActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, YourTicket);

                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PAYPAL_PAYMENT);
                break;
        }

    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult ( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PAYPAL_PAYMENT) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                PaymentConfirmation confirm = data
                        .getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
                if (confirm != null) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Responseeee" + confirm);
                        Log.i("paymentExample", confirm.toJSONObject().toString());


                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(confirm.toJSONObject().toString());

                        String paymentId = jsonObj.getJSONObject("response").getString("id");
                        System.out.println("payment id:-==" + paymentId);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), paymentId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("paymentExample", "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
                    }
                }
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Log.i("paymentExample", "The user canceled.");
            } else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
                Log.i("paymentExample", "An invalid Payment was submitted. Please see the docs.");
            }
        }


    }
```

included the following to manifist

```
    <service android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService" android:exported="false" />

    <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.LoginActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentMethodActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalFuturePaymentActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.FuturePaymentConsentActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.FuturePaymentInfoActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name="io.card.payment.CardIOActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
    <activity android:name="io.card.payment.DataEntryActivity" />
    <!--end of paypal requirements  -->
```

Comment: did you see the example in paypal web: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/android-integration-guide/

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are not starting the service at all, or you forgot to provide the `PayPalConfiguration` extra to the service.  As mentioned in our integration docs, you must start the service as follows:

`Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);
intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
startService(intent);`